# How can I install a new bathroom GFCI receptacle?

Tags: electrical, wiring, safety

How can I install a bathroom GFCI, by connecting it to another outlet?

Comment: Are you trying to add an additional outlet in the bathroom, wired from an existing outlet, and making this additional outlet in the bathroom GFCI?  Is the existing outlet also in the bathroom?  It might make sense to replace the existing outlet in the bathroom with a GFCI outlet, and then protect the new outlet using the LOAD terminals on the GFCI.  Short version: where is the existing outlet and what do you want to protect?

Answer (score 2):

If the only thing in your bathroom that needs to be GFCI protected is a single outlet then you can replace that one outlet with a GFCI outlet.

Comment: GFCI outlets do work without a ground connection.  You are supposed to label the outlet as "no equipment ground".www.mikeholt.com/mojonewsarchive/All-HTML/HTML/GFCI-Receptacles-Without-Ground~19991230.php

Comment: @Grant the link you provided doesn't seem to work, but you are right.

Comment: Pasting from my phone probably broke it.

Comment: GFCI receptacles do not require a ground. In fact replacing ungrounded receptacles with GFCI receptacles is an acceptable, recommended practice (See NEC 406.3(D)(3)(b) & 406.3(D)(3)(c)).